django generic UpdateView with some custom fields
My question is quite close to this one UpdateView with additionnals fields,
so I used the info, but I still lack some details to complete the process
So, I have a simple toy model :
class TxtPlus(models.Model):
    txt = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'TxtPlus<{self.id},{self.txt}>'
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("tplus_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

When editing an instance, I want to add a field, and thus according to the answer above, I define a custom Model
class TxtPlusForm(ModelForm):
    info = CharField(widget=Textarea(attrs={"rows":"2"}))
    class Meta:
        model  = TxtPlus
        fields = ["txt", ]

the using the UpdateView is easy
class TxtPlusUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model         = TxtPlus
    template_name = "adding_to_model_forms/tplus_update.html"
    form_class    = TxtPlusForm

But, what I wish to do is roughly:
def infos_associated_to_object(object):
    return f'there is more about object:{object.pk}'

def test_edit(request,pk):
    object = TxtPlus.objects.get(id=pk)
    info   = infos_associated_to_object(object)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form   = TxtPlusForm(instance=object,initial={'info': info})
        up_log = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form   = TxtPlusForm(request.POST,instance=object)
        up_log = f"change '{info}' to '{form.data['info']}'"
        form.save()
        #... add here form.data['info'] saving
    return render(
        request,
        "adding_to_model_forms/tplus_edit.html",
        {
            "object"  : object,
            "form"    : form,
            "info"    : info,
            "up_log"  : up_log
        }
    )

(of course, infos_associated_to_object, is here a toy version..)
In particular, my problem with UpdateView, is on :
first the part
initial={'info': info} (where info   = infos_associated_to_object(object) )
and then the part
up_log = f"change '{info}' to '{form.data['info']}'"
#... add here form.data['info'] saving
Can you give me some pointers on how to do that using the generic UpdateView ?

The generic UpdateView is meant to be generic. If you want more specificity like the one you have, you have to implement a custom View. Also note that Django’s class based views handle different HTTP methods in different subroutines. I can give you a standard answer but it will not have a resemblance with what you are currently doing.

are you sure these generics aren't meant to be extended for customization purposes ? that would be a pity...

It is the class View that is meant to be customized not generics. Customizing generics should not be done heavily to allow users understand the API. This leaves the purpose of the generic View the same.

I'm still missing the part on initializing the added field (info), but I got the one on post processing :  overriding form_valid() in class TxtPlusUpdateView, .. this is legit, according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms   (...also, there appears to be a typo there "When specifying a custom form class, you must still specify the model, even though the form_class may be a ModelForm." <- it's not may but must be a ModelForm )

got the last one : override get_initial in the derived UpdateView, the object is in self at that moment
